# Reusable ListView where items are colored based on value

Tags: wpf, listview

I want to build a ListView control where you specify two colors, one for if an item is "enabled" and one if it is not.  The ListView would bind to an ObservableCollection where StringBool is a class with a String (the list item text) and bool to enable/disable.

I have started with doing a UserControl, but this feels like it's way overkill.  I can't get my head around how to extend a ListView and attach properties that would be able to be used in the XAML of another window.

Where should I start looking?  I work best from examples :(

Comment: What colour do you want to change?

Comment: I want the textcolor of the ListItem to change.  So that'd be Foreground of the ListViewItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to your `bool` property and sets one or more properties of the `ListViewItem` container, e.g.:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Ok, but how would you make Red and Green settable such that this could be a new control that can be used in other areas?  I ideally want these colors to be independent of each instance

Comment: Settable from where? You could for example use the `DynamicResource` markup extension to reference the brushes in the `Style`:  Value="{DynamicResource EnabledBrush}". You can then define a `Brush` with that key in the scope where you want to change the colours.

Comment: I want this to be a new control that I can use in other xamls.

Comment: New control...? Why would you create a new control to change the foreground of some items?

Comment: Because I could use this control multiple times on the same Window and have it use different colors for each of the items.  I would just have the control level set the colors.

Comment: Then you could define two [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-register-an-attached-property?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and bind to these in the `Style`.